# Is there recording software with bookmark frames on the fly?

Tags: manual-testing

I've taken a look at PSR, which kind of does that, but it's just screen caps, and can only record a certain number. I would rather have a video and and a list of bookmarked frames to jump to in order to review problems that happened.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking here, can you fill in more information and context ?

Comment: Tomas, what do you mean by bookmarking frames on the fly? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, and sorry I failed to make the question more clear. I found that Camtasia has this feature (Add Marker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Camtasia has this feature. In the Camtasia Recorder, you can enable the Effects toolbar, and there's an Add Marker button. When you add the video to the timeline, the markers will appear.